# Parallax site - Img doesn't appear until I scroll

Tags: jquery, css, image, parallax

At my [site](http://mmd3e12dae42.keaweb.dk/test/index.html) I have a logo on the first page, but it doesn't come visible until I start scrolling? How to I make it visible right away?

Here is my html

```
<div id="introwrapper">
    <div id="intro">
    <!--    <div id="introbaggrundforan"></div>-->
    <div id="introbaggrundbagved"></div>
    <a name="section1" class="section1">SECTION 1</a>
    </div> <!--#intro-->
<div id="logo"></div>
```

Here is my Css:

```
#introwrapper {
height: 900px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;   
background: transparent url('images/introbagved.png') no-repeat center;
}


#intro{
background: url('images/introforan.png') no-repeat center;
height: 900px;
width: 1440px;
margin: 0;
position: relative;
z-index: 3;
}

#logo{
background: transparent url('images/logo.png') no-repeat center;
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
position: absolute;
margin-left: 520px;
margin-top: 160px;
z-index: 2;
}
```

Here is my Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(window).bind('scroll',function(e){
                parallaxScroll();
            });


            function parallaxScroll(){
                var scrolledY = $(window).scrollTop();
                $('#logo').css('top','+'+((scrolledY*.819))+'px');
```

Comment: The link to your site is not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
top:0;
```

to the `#logo` css rule.

---

The problem is that you have not defined a location for that element, so it is inserted in relation to the previous elements.. and that is after the `#intro` div.

Answer (score 1):

I think what are you trying to do is make a sticky logo?

```
$doucment.ready
```

Fires once onload.  Your scroll event should be

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
  var scrolledY = $(window).scrollTop();
  $('#logo').css('top','+'+((scrolledY*.819))+'px');
});
```

For IE8 try

```
$("html").scrollTop();
```

Also, your HTML has a missing DIV tag

```
<div id="introwrapper">
    <div id="intro">
        <!--    <div id="introbaggrundforan"></div>-->
        <div id="introbaggrundbagved"></div>
        <a name="section1" class="section1">SECTION 1</a>
    </div> <!--#intro-->
    <div id="logo"></div>
</div> <-- close this
```

Also, it is best practice to leave some data for your blank  tags.